# How do I get an encoded image (png, jpg, etc) out of a Texture2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Below is the code I am trying to modify.

```
static byte[] GetImageAsByteArray(string imageFilePath)
{
    // Open a read-only file stream for the specified file.
    using (FileStream fileStream =
        new FileStream(imageFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        // Read the file's contents into a byte array.
        BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileStream);
        return binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)fileStream.Length);
    }
}
```

As you can see this code uses a file path. I want to pass an image Texture2D into the method like below:

```
static byte[] GetImageAsByteArray(Texture2D image)
```

How do I get the same output as the filestream method but using texture2d. Below is my attempt at it:

```
static byte[] GetImageAsByteArray(Texture2D image)
{
    /* Open a read-only file stream for the specified file.
    using (FileStream fileStream =
        new FileStream(imageFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        */
    {
        // Read the file's contents into a byte array.
        Debug.Log("MADE IT TO GETIMAGESBYTEARR");
       return binaryReader.ReadBytes(image.GetRawTextureData());

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the desired encoding of the image? It gets decoded when it's loaded into the `Texture2D`.

Comment: So the original code uses a file path to reference the image and then passes that file path into the "GetImageAsByteArray()". I want to be able an image that is already loaded in unity and pass the image in through unity not a object. I need the new code that accepts a Texture2D to be the sameoutput as the original code. I honestly do not understand what the original code is outputing

Comment: The original code outputs an array of bytes that is an image encoded in whatever encoding the file was made with. There's no reason it even has to be a valid image file at all. Can you explain what you mean by "pass the imagine in through unity not a object"? I don't understand what that means.

Comment: Currently I have to type the image path in manually, I want to be able to use an image that is already in unity/ saved in the unity project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use an [`ImageConversion`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImageConversion.html) method depending on the encoding you want.

```
Texture2D image;    

// Encodes this texture into EXR format using ZIP compression
byte[] exrEncoded = ImageConversion.EncodeToEXR (image, Texture2D.EXRFlags.CompressZIP);

// Encodes this texture into JPG format
byte[] jpgEncoded = ImageConversion.EncodeToJPG (image);

// Encodes this texture into JPG format
byte[] pngEncoded = EncodeToPNG(image);

// Encodes this texture into TGA format
byte[] tgaEncoded = EncodeToTGA(image);
```

In order to use these, you must set the read/write enabled flag of the texture to true in the texture import settings.

Comment: Thank you for your help!